# Python: Search in file, replace preceding entry

Tags: python, replace

I am trying to alter an existing ASCII data file in a specific way.
The way I would like to go is to find find either one string from an array, which I define beforehand. 
If this string is found in the file I would like to change the preceding entry; the string to put in here depends on which of the strings is found in the first place.

I have a file, where the entrys are separated by spaces and I have trailing spaces at the end to fill up 30 columns. The respective strings would not be in the first line and there would never be more than one per line. An example could look like this:

test01out.txt:

```
a0997 b0998 c0999            
a1000 b1001 c1002            
a1003 b1004 c1005            
a1006 a1000 c1007            
a1008 b1009 c1010            
b1001 b1011 c1012            
a1013 b1014 b1001            
a1015 b1016 c1017
```

The file does not necessarily have to have three columns in a row. It is possible, that a row has only two but can also have four or five columns.

My current attempt was the following:

```
from numpy import *

findlines = open("test01.txt").read().split("\n")
searcharray = array(["a1000","b1001"])
alterarray  = array(["this1","this2"])

tempstring_current = ""
fileout = open("test01out.txt", "w")

for i, line in enumerate(findlines):
    tempstring_last = tempstring_current
    tempstring_current = line.rstrip().split(" "))
    if any(x in tempstring_current for x in searcharray):               # check if one of the elements is in the current line -> unfortunately this seems to be true for any line checked...
        print(i)
        print(tempstring_current)



        for j, element in enumerate(tempstring_current):
            if any(searcharray == tempstring_current):
                currentsearchindex = argmax(searcharray == tempstring_current)

        currentalterstring = alterarray[currentsearchindex]
        if currentsearchindex == 0:
            tempstring_last.split(" ")[-1] = currentalterstring
        else:
            tempstring_current.split(" ")[currentsearchindex - 1] = currentalterstring

        tempstring_current.split(" ")[currentsearchindex-1] = "XPRZeugs_towrite" + repr(currentdesignatedspeed)

    tempstring_last = tempstring_last.ljust(30)
    try: 
        fileout.write(str(tempstring_last))
        fileout.write("\r")
try: 
    fileout.close()
```

searcharray and alterarray would have some more elements, than two. 
I have tested the script up to the any condition; unfortunately the any conditions seems to be met always for some reason I do not quite understand:

```
from numpy import *

findlines = open("test01.txt").read().split("\n")
searcharray = array(["a1000","b1001"])
alterarray  = array(["this1","this2"])

tempstring_current = ""
fileout = open("test01out.txt", "w")

for i, line in enumerate(findlines):
    tempstring_last = tempstring_current
    tempstring_current = line.rstrip().split(" ")
    if any(x in tempstring_current for x in searcharray):               # check if one of the elements is in the current line -> unfortunately this seems to be true for any line checked...
        print(i)
        print(tempstring_current)
```

I get the lines printed for every line in the file, which I did not expect.

---

**Edit/Solution:**

I realized I made a mistake in the input testfile:
It should look like this:

```
a0997 b0998 c0999            
a1000 b1001 c1001            
a1003 b1004 c1005            
a1006 a1000 c1007            
a1008 b1009 c1010            
c1002 b1011 c1012            
a1013 b1014 c1002            
a1015 b1016 c1017
```

The full code doing the job is the following:

```
from numpy import *

findlines = open("test01.txt").read().split("\n")
searcharray = array(["a1000","c1002"])
alterarray  = array(["this1","this2"])

tempstring_current = ""
fileout = open("test01out.txt", "w")

for i, line in enumerate(findlines):
    tempstring_last = tempstring_current
    tempstring_current = line.rstrip().split(" ")
    if any([x in tempstring_current for x in searcharray]):               # check if one of the elements is in the current line -> unfortunately this seems to be true for any line checked...
        # print(i)
        # print(tempstring_current)
        # print(searcharray)
        # print([x in tempstring_current for x in searcharray])
        # print(argmax([x in tempstring_current for x in searcharray]))
        currentsearchposindex = argmax([x in tempstring_current for x in searcharray])      # welchen Index hat das entsprechende Element im Searcharray?

        currentalterstring = alterarray[currentsearchposindex]                              # was ist der entsprechende Eintrag im Alterarray




        for j, currentXPRelement in enumerate(tempstring_current):
            if currentXPRelement == searcharray[currentsearchposindex]:
                currentsearchindex_intemparray = j

        # print(len(tempstring_current))
        # print(searcharray[currentsearchposindex])
        # print(tempstring_current == searcharray[currentsearchposindex])
        # print(searcharray[currentsearchposindex] == tempstring_current)
        # print(argmax(tempstring_current == searcharray[currentsearchposindex]))
        # currentsearchindex_intemparray = argmax(tempstring_current == searcharray[currentsearchposindex])

        if currentsearchindex_intemparray == 0:
            tempstring_last[-1] = currentalterstring
        else:
            tempstring_current[currentsearchindex_intemparray - 1] = currentalterstring

        # tempstring_current[currentsearchindex_intemparray-1] = "XPRZeugs_towrite" + repr(currentalterstring)

    tempstring_last = str(" ".join(tempstring_last)).ljust(30)
    if not i == 0:
        try: 
            fileout.write(str(tempstring_last))
            fileout.write("\r")
        finally:
            None   


try: 
    fileout.write(" ".join(tempstring_current))
    fileout.write("\r")
    fileout.close()
finally:
    None
```

Comment: let me get it clear for me, you want to search items in `searcharray` but array items may not be placed side by side in the input file, right?

Comment: if I wanted to change the preceding entries, I'd walk backwards though the file and read each line from right to left. This would make things much easier...

Comment: Have you tried expanding the any expression into for loops, so you can print intermediate steps to debug it? Also that way you can print the x that matches.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your code so at least it can fail to always match, change

```
if any(x in tempstring_current for x in searcharray):
```

to

```
if any([x in tempstring_current for x in searcharray]):
```

I think the reason is that the 'x in tempstring_current for x in searcharray' expression returns an interator function - any() says 'this value (i.e. the iterator function reference) is not None so it is True', so the result is always True. The changed syntax creates a list from the iterator and then any works as you probably wanted, i.e. it returns true if any element in the list is true.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. I will post the complete solution in a minute.